# ConcurrentHashmap does need synchronization in my implementation?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I am having some troubles by seeing if something needs to be synchronized or not, i will show you my sample solution.
Do i actually need my methods synchronized? Or would there be a better approach?
Because ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe by itself, the question arises because i have two of them, then i think i should synchronize the methods to not get the two maps out of sync, right?

The BookService is annotated with @Service, which implies it beeing a singleton.

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, UUID> codeToUUIDs;
    private final ConcurrentMap<Book, String> bookToCodes;

    public BookService() {
        this.bookToCodes = fillBookCodes();
        this.codeToUUIDs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public synchronized UUID add(Book book) {
        final String randomCode = bookToCodes.putIfAbsent(book, "randomCode");
        return codeToUUIDs.get(randomCode);
    }

    public synchronized UUID get(String code) {
        return codeToUUIDs.get(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code to add to `codeToUUIDs`? Because if you don't, you don't need synchronization, you can just return `null`.

Comment: It sorta depends on your needs.  That code will not throw any concurrent mod exceptions or other weird access problems if you remove `synchronized` from your method, but it could be that a book is in `bookToCodes` but not yet in `codeToUUIDs` during a `get`.  If that is ok, then you can remove `synchronized` from your methods, but if you want the operations to `BookService` to be atomic, then keep the `synchronized`.  Based on code provided, I see no need for `synchronized`, but not sure if there's more to this.

Comment: Thanks, there is a little bit more to this, i just made a short sample and more simplified from the something i have done today and i was wondering how i could make it better. But needing both methods in sync and then i dont need concurrentMaps helps already.

Comment: In the code of the question, I see no risk to have inconsistency in the maps. Maybe in the real code you may have but maybe not. The accepted and upvoted answer is very misleading as it gives the feeling that we have to synchronize any methods that use two maps.

Comment: Ok, tomorrow i will post another version of that which will make it more clear. I removed the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

Since both of maps need to be in sync, you need to use `synchronized` methods.

But since your methods are already synchronized, you don't need ConcurrentMaps here. Usual HashMaps are okay.

Answer (score 1):

The access to the map have to be synchronized only if you have a race condition that may create a not desirable inconsistency in the map content.
It may the case even by using a single map.

Actually you don't have any race condition in the get() and the add() methods. So synchronization is helpless.

suppose the add() method changed the state of one map according to what you put in the other, you would have a race condition and in this case, external synchronization would be required.